# Google App Engine with Telegram Bot API through PHP output no whitespace

Tags: php, google-app-engine, telegram-bot

So, I configure my PHP script to send message from my contact form to my telegram chat with a bot.

Here's the PHP script code:

```
<?php
if(trim($_POST["gotcha"]) !== "") {
  header("Location: https://example.com/");
} else {
  if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["subject"]) && isset($_POST["content"])) {

    $wholeMessage = "Name:"." ".$_POST["name"]." "."|"." "."Email:"." ".$_POST["email"]." "."|"." "."Subject:"." ".$_POST["subject"]." "."|"." "."Message:"." ".$_POST["content"];
    $data = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOTID>/sendmessage?chat_id=<CHATID>&text=".$wholeMessage;

    $response = file_get_contents($data);

    header("Location: https://example.com/thanks/");
  } else {
    header("Location: https://example.com/");
  }
}
?>
```

The result on my Telegram chat:

```
Name:firstname|Email:mail@mail.com|Subject:test|Message:testhttps://google.commouseappletest
```

Using `%nbsp;` only output:

```
Name:
```

with nothing else outputted.

As you can see, all the whitespace has disappeared. 
Is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `URL Encode`.

- Use `%20` as whitespace.
- Or use `urlencode()` function to encode your url.

This can also rid your code of the danger of strange errors, especially when you are using a url containing Chinese or other special characters without url encode.